# Why did the Marshall Court actually rule that part of the Judiciary Act was unconstitutional?

Tags: constitutional-law, us-constitution, us-supreme-court

*Marbury v. Madison*, [5 U.S. 137](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/5/137/) (1803), decided by the U.S. Supreme Court's Marshall Court, is famous for being the case most strongly associated with giving the court the power to rule statutes unconstitutional.

But I am not convinced by the decision that the congress was incorrect to begin with, and even if they were, that there is certainty in that belief that the congress should be second guessed.

Writs of mandamus were accepted parts of law in general, state courts had that power, and the design of the judicial branch is largely up to congress by legislation, and Article III expressly states that the regulations and exceptions are up to congress.

Was it really that necessary to actually declare it unconstitutional?

It doesn't scream unconstitutional the way that *Obergefells vs Hodges*, [576 U.S. 644](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/576/644/) (2015), did.

Comment: Why a judge or group of judges did something is opinion based. The only one who could answer that is them.

Comment: @Trish Not at all, why a judge did something should be right there in the judgement.

Comment: @DaleM "Was it really that necessary to actually declare it unconstitutional?" - that's an opinion question

Comment: @Trish courts don’t actually declare an act unconstitutional, they just give their reasons why the can’t enforce it.

Comment: @DaleM, https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/98786/do-courts-declare-acts-of-the-legislature-unconstitutional.  And just like that a response appears in the form of a Q&A!

Comment: @DaleM in _Marbury,_ the reason was that the law was "repugnant to the constitution," and further that "laws repugnant to the constitution are void."  There's not much difference between that and declaring a law to be unconstitutional.

Answer (score 2):

The "actual" reason that the U.S. Supreme Court ruled that part of the Judiciary Act was unconstitutional, in *Marbury v. Madison*, [5 U.S. 137](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/5/137/) (1803), is, **by definition**, the reason stated in the linked opinion of the U.S. Supreme Court.

Marybury filed his case directly in the U.S. Supreme Court requesting that Secretary of State Madison recognize his appointment as a Justice of the Peace in the District of Columbia.

The U.S. Supreme Court broke the case up into three issues:

> 1. Has the applicant a right to the commission he demands?
> 2. If he has a right, and that right has been violated, do the laws of his country afford him a remedy?
> 3. If they do afford him a remedy, is it a mandamus issuing from this court?

The Court concluded that Marbury had a right to the commission he demanded, and that this was a judicially enforceable right.

The resolution of the issue that the case is remembered for is whether a writ of mandamus from the U.S. Supreme Court was the proper remedy when Marbury was denied his commission.

The U.S. Supreme Court noted that the Judiciary Act gave it the power to issue writs without limitation. But it also noted that the U.S. Constitution did not give the U.S. Supreme Court original jurisdiction over the subject-matter of the case in question.

Article III, Section 2 of the U.S. Constitution stated in the pertinent part:

> In all Cases affecting Ambassadors, other public Ministers and
> Consuls, and those in which a State shall be Party, the supreme Court
> shall have original Jurisdiction. In all the other Cases before
> mentioned, the supreme Court shall have appellate Jurisdiction, both
> as to Law and Fact, with such Exceptions, and under such Regulations
> as the Congress shall make.

The U.S. Supreme Court summarized the pertinent part of the Judiciary Act as follows:

> The act to establish the judicial courts of the United States
> authorizes the Supreme Court
>
> "to issue writs of mandamus, in cases warranted by the principles and
> usages of law, to any courts appointed, or persons holding office,
> under the authority of the United States."

So, it held that the Judiciary Act language allowing it to issue writs, even in a case that was not an appeal from another court, and was not within constitutionally prescribed original jurisdiction of the U.S. Supreme Court, was unconstitutional.

In other words, it told Marbury that he should have sought relief in the U.S. District Court for the District of Columbia, and then appeal the case to the U.S. Supreme Court if he was unsatisfied, rather than filing his case directly with the U.S. Supreme Court.

This may seem like a petty procedural question, unlike landmark cases resolving questions of the individual rights of large numbers of people under the U.S. Constitution. But it had great importance to the U.S. Supreme Court as an institution.

If the U.S. Supreme Court had ruled the other way, every single federal petition for a writ of mandamus (or any other common law writ) could have been brought directly in the U.S. Supreme Court. This would have deluged the U.S. Supreme Court with far more cases than it would otherwise have to deal with, if those cases were resolved in the first instance by federal trial courts.

To provide some context, as of 2023, [more than 10% of cases filed in U.S. District Courts](https://www.uscourts.gov/file/77005/download) (in excess of 33,000 cases a year) are petitions for common law writs. Also, keep in mind that [until 1891](https://uscourts.gov/educational-resources/educational-activities/evarts-act-creating-modern-appellate-courts), the U.S. Supreme Court was the sole appellate court in the federal system, because no intermediate appellate courts had been established yet, so dealing with appeals alone already provided plenty of work to keep the U.S. Supreme Court busy. Then, as now, cases in the U.S. Supreme Court's constitutionally prescribed original jurisdiction only account for 1-2% of the U.S. Supreme Court's case load.

Given the seeming clarity of the portion of the Judiciary Act known as the [All Writs Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Writs_Act) at the time, though, from a statutory perspective, Marbury was correct. He was statutorily entitled to file his case seeking a writ of mandamus against the U.S. Secretary of State in the U.S. Supreme Court. So, holding that the statute was unconstitutional was the clearest and most legally supportable way for the U.S. Supreme Court to align the law regarding its own jurisdiction with the U.S. Constitution.

Notably, this was not just meddling with a decision of Congress based upon a policy disagreement. It was fundamentally a separation of powers issue.

Could Congress order the U.S. Supreme Court to deal with cases in its original jurisdiction in a manner directly contrary to the allocation of cases between the U.S. Supreme Courts and lower courts set forth in the Article III of the U.S. Constitution?

The U.S. Supreme Court held that Congress could not order it to take on this additional case load.

Also, the principle of U.S. Constitutional supremacy over federal statutes, while a landmark determination to establish in case law and a stark difference from the structure of the British government, was really not that big of a deal. It was a bedrock assumption of the U.S. Constitution that was widely shared by the Founders and the legal community of the time, that just happened to finally come up in this case. It was not a "shocking" in the eyes of the legal community at the time.

In the wake of this decision, the All Writs Act, now codified at 28 U.S.C. § 1651, was rewritten. It now says:

> (a)The Supreme Court and all courts established by Act of Congress may
> issue all writs necessary or appropriate in aid of their respective
> jurisdictions and agreeable to the usages and principles of law.
>
> (b)An alternative writ or rule nisi may be issued by a justice or
> judge of a court which has jurisdiction.

Comment: The Supreme Court is under no obligation to be organized with a few judges all hearing a case. The Dutch have dozens of judges on the supreme court and a panel of a few of them hear most cases, like a mundane writ of mandamus. If the workload gets to be too much, why not just do something like that? That is how federal appeals courts are organized.

Comment: @R-Obsessive (1) Congress has to authorize it - keep in mind that this was a 4-0 decision, (2) nobody in the U.S. legal system would have imagined that possibility in 1803, (3) it still wouldn't be consistent with the language of the constitution.

Answer (score 0):

### Because the Act purported to give the court original jurisdiction beyond what was given in the Constitution

[Marbury v. Madison](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/5/137/#tab-opinion-1958607), 5 U.S. 137 (1803) dealt with a conflict between the Judiciary Act and the Constitution about the Supreme Court’s jurisdiction.

The Constitution gives the Supreme Court appellate jurisdiction in general, but original jurisdiction only in a short list of specifically enumerated cases. The Judiciary Act of 1801 gave the Court original jurisdiction to issue writs of Mandamus to Federal officials - this is not one of the situations enumerated in the Constitution.

It was never in doubt that the Court had the power to issue such writs; what was in doubt was their jurisdiction to hear the case in the first place.

A court may only render a decision where the case falls within its jurisdiction, as a simple example, a small claims court only has jurisdiction over disputes up to a specified monetary amount. In addition, in a sort of snake eating its tail situation, courts have jurisdiction to decide if they have jurisdiction, so, they can issue a legitimate judgement that amounts to “we can’t issue a judgement”.

So, on the one hand, the Court has the Judiciary Act that says they have original jurisdiction over this case, and on the other hand they have the Constitution that lists when they have original jurisdiction and this case doesn’t fall into any of the categories.

The Court decides 4-0, that when an Act conflicts with the Constitution, they have to follow the Constitution. They do this by reasoning:

- Courts have to resolve conflicts between laws all the time and have historically had the power to do so,
- The Constitution states that it is the highest law of the land and has specific provisions for changing it - which don’t include simple Acts by Congress,
- The judges are required to swear an oath to uphold the Constitution,
- Therefore, the Constitution wins and, in this particular case, they don’t have original jurisdiction. That is, Congress can neither expand or narrow the powers of the SUpreme Court beyond that which are in the Constitution.

While people talk of declaring a law unconstitutional as though it’s a dramatic stand by the courts against the legislature it’s actually more of a simple, “Sorry, we can’t enforce that law.”

Your suggestion that Congress can design the judicial branch by legislation is true **except for the Supreme Court**. The United States Supreme Court’s jurisdiction is detailed in the Constitution and cannot be changed without an amendment. Congress can change other things, like the number of justices, because the Constitution says they can. Congress could (and has) also create other Federal Courts that do have the jurisdiction to issue writs of Mandamus to Federal officials and the Supreme Court would have appellate jurisdiction over those courts - but the Judiciary Act of 1801 didn’t do that - it tried to give the Court original jurisdiction and that’s a no-no.

Comment: It says in all other cases, with the exceptions that Congress prescribes.